# mongo index of data still exists when documents expire according to TTL

Tags: mongodb

I wanted mongodb to delete old data automatically, so I set TTL to be 48 hours. Now it turns out the data are gone while the index remains, which occupies a large amount of RAM in the servers.

Why does this happen?  How can I ensure that index and the data expire simultaneously?

[image]

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you using, and what storage engine?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am using Mongodb 3.4 and the storage engine is WiredTiger.